# Standard error of values in array corresponding to values in another array

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, standard-error

I have an array that contains numbers that are distances, and another that represents certain values at that distance. How do I calculate the standard error of all the data at a fixed value of the distance?

The standard error is the standard deviation/ the square-root of the number of observations.

e.g distances(d):

```
[1 1 14 6 1 12 14 6 6 7 4 3 7 9 1 3 3 6 5 8]
```

e.g data corresponding to the entry of the distances:

therefore value=3.3 at d=1; value=2,1 at d=1; value=3.5 at d=14; etc..

```
[3.3 2.1 3.5 2.5 4.6 7.4 2.6 7.8 9.2 10.11 14.3 2.5 6.7 3.4 7.5 8.5 9.7 4.3 2.8 4.1]
```

For example, at distance d=6 I should calculate the standard error of 2.5, 7.8, 9.2 and 4.3 which would be the standard deviation of these values divided by the square root of the total number of values (4 in this case).

I've used the following code that works, but I don't know how to divide the result be the square-root of the total number of values at each distance:

```
import numpy as np

result = []
for d in set(key): 
    result.append(np.std[dist[i] for i in range(len(key)) if key[i] == d])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `distances_list.count(distance)` to get the number of occurrences of whatever distance you're working with.

Comment: Also in your code, what is key?

Comment: Sorry, key is the array with distances. I should've specified.

Comment: Wait `dist` is not the distances? I assumed that `key` contains the values. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
for d in set(key): 
    result.append(np.std[dist[i] for i in range(len(key)) if key[i] == d] / np.sqrt(dist.count(d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of a hard time telling exactly how you want things structured, but I would recommend a dictionary, so that you can know which result is associated with which key value. If your data is like this:

```
>>> key
array([ 1,  1, 14,  6,  1, 12, 14,  6,  6,  7,  4,  3,  7,  9,  1,  3,  3,
        6,  5,  8])
>>> values
array([ 3.3 ,  2.1 ,  3.5 ,  2.5 ,  4.6 ,  7.4 ,  2.6 ,  7.8 ,  9.2 ,
       10.11, 14.3 ,  2.5 ,  6.7 ,  3.4 ,  7.5 ,  8.5 ,  9.7 ,  4.3 ,
        2.8 ,  4.1 ])
```

You can set up a dictionary along these lines with a dict comprehension:

```
result = {f'distance_{i}':np.std(values[key==i]) / np.sqrt(sum(key==i)) for i in set(key)}
>>> result
{'distance_1': 1.0045988005169029, 'distance_3': 1.818424226264781, 'distance_4': 0.0, 'distance_5': 0.0, 'distance_6': 1.3372079120316331, 'distance_7': 1.2056170619230633, 'distance_8': 0.0, 'distance_9': 0.0, 'distance_12': 0.0, 'distance_14': 0.3181980515339463}
```